# вывод простых чисел с массива JS (помогите найти ошибку)

Tags: javascript

уважаемые форумчане.
Хочу вывести в консоль числа с массива и прописать возле каждого простое они или нет.
Консоль выводит, что число 5 и далее до конца массива это все не простые числа.
Помогите найти ошибку в коде, уже мозг закипает:

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
let flag = true;

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   for (let j = 2; j < i; j++) {
      if (arr[i] % j == 0) {
         flag = false;
         break;
      }
   }

   if (flag) {
      console.log(`${arr[i]} ПРОСТОЕ ЧИСЛО`);
   } else {
      console.log(`${arr[i]} НЕ простое число`);
   }

}
```

Comment: После нахождения числа не являющегося простым, вы нигде не восстанавливаете исходное состояние переменной `flag`.

Comment: Перенесите `let flag = true` внутрь цикла.

Comment: @Yaant Разницы никакой от переноса внутрь цикла

Comment: @KlimenkoKirill Обоснуйте? Вон, в ответе ниже именно это и сделано, и все сразу заработало.

Comment: спасибо огромное за уделенное ваше время и помощь!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Переопределяйте flag внутри начала цикла или используйте объявление в начале цикла.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   let flag = true;
   
   for (let j = 2; j < i; j++) {
      if (arr[i] % j == 0) {
         flag = false;
         break;
      }
   }

   if (flag) {
      console.log(`${arr[i]} ПРОСТОЕ ЧИСЛО`);
   } else {
      console.log(`${arr[i]} НЕ простое число`);
   }

}
```

Comment: Добавьте в ваше решение пример [10,10,8,9] и вы удивитесь, увидев, что ваше решение определяет все до единой цифры в массиве, как простые числа, хотя по факту простые числа в данном массиве отсутствуют.